# connect to C# server from javascript

Tags: javascript, sockets, websocket

Is it possible to create a javascript program that connect to a simple C# server using a simple socket and not a WebSocket.

can you help me with a sample.

Comment: JavaScript running where? In a browser? In a console? On a server?

Comment: JavaScript running in a browser

Comment: No you cannot use socket connection in browser, access socket directly from the browser is never going to happen because it opens up a huge risk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no standard way to make a TCP connection from Javascript code running in a web browser.  (See the answer by @Johannes Hahn)

To communicate between your client and server, consider Microsoft's [SignalR](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/getting-started/introduction-to-signalr) library.  It is designed to allow a Javascript program, running in the browser, to communicate with a C# server.  SignalR will use websockets; however, it will continue to work if websockets are not available by falling back to other transports.  You can also specify transports, if you need to prevent it from attempting to use websockets.

> SignalR connection starts as HTTP, and is then promoted to a WebSocket connection if it is available. WebSocket is the ideal transport for SignalR, since it makes the most efficient use of server memory, has the lowest latency, and has the most underlying features (such as full duplex communication between client and server), but it also has the most stringent requirements: WebSocket requires the server to be using Windows Server 2012 or Windows 8, and .NET Framework 4.5. If these requirements are not met, SignalR will attempt to use other transports to make its connections.

---

Also, be aware that if your Javascript is *not* running in a web browser, you *can* make regular network connections.  For example, a Javascript application running on Node.js.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that at least Firefox is supposed to know about socket, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/TCP_Socket_API. But (taken from the same source) TCP or UDP sockets are not part of any standard and therefore likely either unsupported or completely different in other browsers.

Answer (score 0):

In principle no. For security reasons browsers only allow a limited set of protocols. Chrome has a socket API, but that is not standard - https://developer.chrome.com/apps/sockets_tcp. There are solutions which use a WebSocket connection to a server which then establishes a TCP socket connection, e.g. https://github.com/kanaka/websockify, http://artemyankov.com/tcp-client-for-browsers/, so if you can't add WebSocket directly to the server you may want to check these out.